# How to achieve gravity="center_vertical" in a RelativeLayout nested within a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, center, android-relativelayout

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SDDnAG-jkQjC6F85iPgfv3Et1pYl8t03k-TkCN3YcCw/edit

---

I have an Android preference page containing a mixture of stock, and custom List Items. The custom list items "Mood" and "Mixed Mood" can be seen in the screen shot in the referenced Google Doc, and function in the following way. (The external link is because, without a reputation of at leat 10, I'm not allowed to post images in stackoverflow...)

1) Before a user has chosen a value, they simply display their title. (either Mood or MixedMood)

2) After a user has chosen a value, they display their title AND a custom tool tip (the little colored squares), indicating their choice.

THE PROBLEM: You can see from the screen shot that before a user has chosen a value, the "Mood" text is not centered. I would like for it to be centered, and then dynamically make room for the custom tool tip after a choice is made. In other words, I would like

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
```

To respond to

```
android:gravity="center_vertical".
```

Is this possible?

My layout file looks like this.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:gravity="center_vertical" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" 
         android:layout_marginRight="6dip"> 

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <!-- This image represents the dropdown arrow -->
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/title"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_round_more_normal_cropped" />

        <monarca_rct.client.customcomponents.MoodScalePresentation
            android:id="@+android:id/hpmp_mood_scale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:paddingTop="4.0dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right:

You can set `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` in `<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"` for more info visit http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Comment: Thanks Murat! The "Layout Tricks" article you posted is very similar to what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, after reading that article, experimenting a little more, and also including your `layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` suggestion, it still isn't centering. I'm stumped...

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly try this out but I think it might be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dip"
    //REMOVED GRAVITY
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         //REMOVED GRAVITY
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" 
         android:layout_marginRight="6dip"> 

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <!-- This image represents the dropdown arrow -->
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/title"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_round_more_normal_cropped" />

        <monarca_rct.client.customcomponents.MoodScalePresentation
            android:id="@+android:id/hpmp_mood_scale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:paddingTop="4.0dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The reason to go from **center_vertical** to **center_vertical|left** is because your parent layout is like a grid and you can "choose" your position. So if you have:

(1) (2) (3)

(4) (5) (6)

(7) (8) (9)

[Don't mind the white spaces between each line, for some reason if I don't do it like that it gets displayed all in one line.]

The **4** is where you want your text. As you can see, the 4 is on the **left** but also **vertically centered** hence the combination:

```
 android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
```

Quick question, why do you need a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout? You could do without the LinearLayout altogether from the looks of it.